# Tensorflow Data API .map() Problems

Tags: tensorflow

### Context

I'm working on an image multi-classifier and I am running into issues when I'm building out the `dataset` using the `td.data` API. I currently have ~33k images with labels.

I'm running this out of a Jupyter Notebook on SageMaker.

### Question

Why is the `dataset.map()` function passing values (Tensor) to the `parse_function` which doesn't seem to be readable for normalizing the images?

### Details

Here are the (truncated) functions I'm using:

```
def parse_function(filename, label): 
    print("_____________________")
    print(filename)
    print("_____________________")
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(
        requests.get(filename).content, channels=3, name="jpeg_reader")
    image_resized = tf.image.resize(image_decoded, [IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE])
    image_normalized = image_resized / 255.0
    return image_normalized, label

def create_dataset(filenames, labels, is_training=True):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
    # My problem seems to be here with the .map()
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls=3)
    dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset
```

The data I’m passing to the create_dataset function looks like this:

```
https://<image URL #1>, [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
https://<image URL #2>, [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

The `.map()` function passes the individual "rows" off as it's iterating through, but the returned values are empty. When I print the filename, I’m getting a Tensor:

```
Tensor("args_0:0", shape=(), dtype=string)
```

But if I manually pass the URL and label to the parse_function, I get the desired results. For example:

```
d = parse_function(X_train.iloc[1], y_train_bin[1])
print(d)
```

Gives me the following (truncated for brevity):

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[0.02282913, 0.0670168 , 0.08235294],
        [0.02282913, 0.0670168 , 0.08235294],
        [0.02282913, 0.0670168 , 0.08235294],
        ...,
        [0.2901961 , 0.37254903, 0.3764706 ]]], dtype=float32)>, array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
```